# ImageMagick conflict on Ubuntu running webbrick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ubuntu, installation, imagemagick

I am trying to install [refinerycms](http://refinerycms.com/), a Ruby on Rails CMS on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. I run `rails server` and I get the following exception:

```
carcher@carcher-laptop:~/Code/tgc$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.12.2/lib/RMagick2.so: This installation of RMagick was configured with ImageMagick 6.6.4 but ImageMagick 6.5.7-8 is in use. (RuntimeError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.12.2/lib/RMagick.rb:11
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dragonfly-0.7.6/lib/dragonfly/analysis/r_magick_analyser.rb:1
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dragonfly-0.7.6/lib/dragonfly/config/r_magick.rb:15:in `apply_configuration'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dragonfly-0.7.6/lib/dragonfly/configurable.rb:33:in `configure'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dragonfly-0.7.6/lib/dragonfly/config/r_magick.rb:14:in `apply_configuration'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dragonfly-0.7.6/lib/dragonfly/configurable.rb:39:in `configure_with'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/refinerycms-0.9.8.2/vendor/refinerycms/images/lib/images.rb:10
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
    from /home/carcher/Code/tgc/config/environment.rb:5
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /home/carcher/Code/tgc/config.ru:3
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
    from /home/carcher/Code/tgc/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /home/carcher/Code/tgc/config.ru:1
carcher@carcher-laptop:~/Code/tgc$
```

I built and installed ImageMagick 6.6.4 from source following the instructions [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php#unix) and BEFORE I did that I removed the ImageMagick tools that were pre-installed in Ubuntu, to avoid any conflicts. But still I seem to have this version 6.5.7 around.

I guess my question is how do I remove/disable `ImageMagick 6.5.7-8`?

Thanks in advance for the help, I'm all out of ideas.

Cheers, Ciaran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm up and running! I did a clean Ubuntu install, and just used the pre-installed Imagemagick package. The [Refinery CMS tutorial](http://tutorials.refinerycms.org/tutorials/how-to-install-refinery-prerequisites)  for Lunix omits a few things a novice like me needs to do, so I documented all my steps [here](http://flydillonfly.wordpress.com/2010/09/17/setting-up-refinerycms-on-ubuntu-10-04-lts/).

The main problem was that early in the process when I ran into an issue with RMagick, I presumed I needed a later version of Imagemagick so I downloaded and installed it from source. There is no need to do that - none at all. The version 6.5.7-8 will do just fine and play well with RMagick and with RefineryCMS.

Hope this helps others.

If you need to use the latest version then I found this post that might help. I haven't tried it though:

http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=557778

I [posted](http://groups.google.com/group/refinery-cms/browse_thread/thread/9023e1d7c505e831) this info on the RefineryCMS Google message board too.

Cheers,
Ciaran

Answer (score 0):

Lots of help at the Refinery Google group: http://groups.google.com/group/refinery-cms. Or have you tried that already?

Comment: I'll try there - thought this was a more general issue so posted here. Thanks.